# How to fix OS X proxy settings being ignored?

Tags: macos, networking, proxy

I've been tweaking my proxy .pac file, and updating the AirPort proxy settings several times. At some point it seemed that OS X began ignoring the proxy settings completely.

In the `System Preferences > AirPort > Advanced > Proxies` I see the correct file url and the `Automatic Proxy Configuration` is checked (yes, I remembered to "Apply" and save my changes), but browsers are ignoring the proxy. In addition, I get this:

```
$ networksetup -getwebproxy AirPort
Enabled: No
Server: 
Port: 0
Authenticated Proxy Enabled: 0
```

Even if I try using the command line with:

```
$ networksetup -setautoproxyurl AirPort http://path/to/my.pac
```

the command exits with no error message and the proxy still isn't considered nor the `-getwebproxy` command show that a proxy is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the PAC file is valid?  I just tried setting both an invalid PAC url and a valid url pointing to an invalid file; neither gave me any errors (or useful log entries that I could find), they were just silently ignored.

Comment: I think you're right. Is there some way to test PAC files and get an intelligible indications of what's the error in them?

Comment: @UrEI: Try [pacparser](http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/) -- I haven't used it, but the .dmg download for OS X includes a pactester program that looks like it should do the job.